# nExtend not working with a option if Statement

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a option variable true or false (else) if the option onetime is selected then for select case go WITHOUT `nExtend`, else add a `nExtend` (yes I have two select cases see code). I am getting a error on Application-defined. Any help would be greatly appreciated full code below.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()


    Dim irow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim iCol As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim value As Long
    Dim NewPart As Boolean
    Dim ws_warehouse(7) As Worksheet    '7 is total warehouse tab you have
    Dim nExtend As Integer
    Dim cel As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("Main")

    Set ws_warehouse(1) = Worksheets("Elkhart East")
    Set ws_warehouse(2) = Worksheets("Tennessee")
    Set ws_warehouse(3) = Worksheets("Alabama")
    Set ws_warehouse(4) = Worksheets("North Carolina")
    Set ws_warehouse(5) = Worksheets("Pennsylvania")
    Set ws_warehouse(6) = Worksheets("Texas")
    Set ws_warehouse(7) = Worksheets("West Coast")

    Set c = ws.Range("A7:A1048576").Find(What:=Me.PartTextBox.value, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If c Is Nothing Then
    'find first empty row in database
        lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        irow = lastRow + 1
        NewPart = True
    Else
    'find row where the part is
        irow = ws.Cells.Find(What:=Me.PartTextBox.value, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
        NewPart = False
    End If

    'check for a part number
    If Trim(Me.PartTextBox.value) = "" Then
      Me.PartTextBox.SetFocus
      MsgBox "Please Enter A Part Number"
      Exit Sub
    End If

    If Trim(Me.MonthComboBox.value) = "" Then
      Me.MonthComboBox.SetFocus
      MsgBox "Please Enter A Month"
      Exit Sub
    End If

    If Trim(Me.AddTextBox.value) = "" Then
      Me.AddTextBox.SetFocus
      MsgBox "Please Enter A Value To Add Or Substract"
      Exit Sub
    End If




    For Each Cel2 In .Cells(irow, iCol).Resize(, nExtend)
        If Onetimeoption.value = True Then
            Select Case MonthComboBox.value
                Case "Current Month"
                    iCol = "C"
                Case "Current Month +1"
                    iCol = "N"
                Case "Current Month +2"
                    iCol = "O"
                Case "Current Month +3"
                    iCol = "P"
                Case "Current Month +4"
                    iCol = "Q"
            End Select
        Else
            nExtend = 1 'Set this as a default.
            Select Case MonthComboBox.value
                Case "Current Month"
                    iCol = "C"

                Case "Current Month +1"
                    iCol = "N"
                    nExtend = 4
                Case "Current Month +2"
                    iCol = "O"
                    nExtend = 3
                Case "Current Month +3"
                    iCol = "P"
                    nExtend = 2
                Case "Current Month +4"
                    iCol = "Q"
            End Select
        End If

        actWarehouse = Me.warehousecombobox.ListIndex + 1
        With ws
            .Cells(irow, "A").value = Me.PartTextBox.value

            For Each Cel1 In .Cells(irow, iCol).Resize
                For Each Cel2 In .Cells(irow, iCol).Resize(, nExtend)
                    Cel1.value = Cel2.value + CLng(Me.AddTextBox.value)
                    Cel1.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                Next Cel2
            Next Cel1
        End With

  With ws_warehouse(actWarehouse)
        'find part number
        l_row = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        NewPart = True
        For r = 7 To l_row
            If Trim(.Range("A" & r)) = "" Then Exit For
            If LCase(.Range("A" & r)) = LCase(Me.PartTextBox.Text) Then
                irow = r
                Exit For
                NewPart = False
            End If
        Next r
        If NewPart Then irow = r

        .Cells(irow, "A").value = Me.PartTextBox.value
        For Each cel In .Cells(irow, iCol).Resize(, nExtend)
            cel.value = cel.value + CLng(Me.AddTextBox.value)
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Next cel
    End With

    'clear the data
    Me.PartTextBox.value = ""
    Me.MonthComboBox.value = ""
    Me.AddTextBox.value = ""
    Me.PartTextBox.SetFocus
    Me.warehousecombobox.value = ""

End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'Empty NameTextBox
     PartTextBox.value = ""

    'Empty PhoneTextBox
     AddTextBox.value = ""

    'Empty DinnerComboBox

    'Fill DinnerComboBox
    With MonthComboBox
         .AddItem "Current Month"
         .AddItem "Current Month +1"
         .AddItem "Current Month +2"
         .AddItem "Current Month +3"
         .AddItem "Current Month +4"

    End With

    With warehousecombobox
        .AddItem "Elkhart East"
        .AddItem "Tennessee"
        .AddItem "Alabama"
        .AddItem "North Carolina"
        .AddItem "Pennsylvania"
        .AddItem "Texas"
        .AddItem "West Coast"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is this *supposed* to do? You have 2 *identical* `Select Case` blocks.

Comment: _I am getting a error on Application-defined_ Can you ellaborate? What is then error code and an error message?

Comment: @Comintern except one of the select case contains the nExtend and one doesn't

Comment: @litelite when I run my macro it runs a form, upon me selecting one time option field button and run. The select case without the nExtend should execute however it's highlighting the following code: For Each Cel2 In .Cells(irow, iCol).Resize(, nExtend)

Comment: `nExtend = 1` is ***outside*** the `Select Case`.  Again, what is this code supposed to do?

Comment: @Luis can you post the rest of the code? like the whole sub. and tell us what is the error message that appear when the editor highlight the code

Comment: @litelite full code posted and error states Compile error invalid or unqualified reference line:  For Each Cel2 In .Cells(irow, iCol).Resize(, nExtend)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.Cells(...)` but it  is not in a `With` block, expressions starting with a dot(.) or exclamation mark(!) cannot appear outside of a with block. You need to use either `Cells(...)` (Without a leading dot) or `ActiveSheet.Cells(...)` Both are equivalent.